# HTML / Angular input validation - Allow numbers and dots, not dashes

Tags: html, angular, input

I have an AngularForm which binds the formControlName to an input field that is of type `number`.

I would like to accept numbers and dots only. Unfortunately the HTML attribute tag `number` also accepts dashes. This is something that I would like to prevent. Is there another attribute that could work within the HTML, or is there a suitable regEx expression that would only allow numbers and dots?

**HTML**

```
<input name="myNumber" step="any" type="number" formControlName="myNumber">
```

**Angular Form / TS**

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
  question_number: null,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a custom directive with this regex /[^0-9.]/g, this should remove any other character other than numbers and dot

Directive code:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[numberAndDot]"
})
export class NumberAndDotDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('input') inputChange() {

      this.element.nativeElement.value = this.element.nativeElement.value
      .replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')
      // Replace extra dots
      .replace('.', '%FD%')
      .replace(/\./g, '')
      .replace('%FD%', '.');
  }
}
```

Template code:

```html
<input numberAndDot name="myNumber" step="any" formControlName="myNumber">
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! - I added the validator code to my component which errors when typing 'dashes' into the input. It also doesn't accept dots for decimals. (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length'))

Comment: you do not want the error state? updated the code this should solve the error

Comment: Thanks. No luck unfortunately. Dashes are still possible to enter into the input.

Comment: ah, you want to prevent dashes from being entered

Comment: Yes correct! Sorry, I should have been more explicit.

Comment: use a directive in that case, I have updated the answer please check

Comment: Thanks! - Nearly there. Some slightly odd behaviour though. When pressing `.` it moves the cursor to the beginning of the input even after enter any amount of numbers

Comment: the regex was a little tricky, remove type="number" and add the code to replace extra dots

Comment: Thanks a ton! I think this is nearly there. No dashes, which is great. It does however allow for multiple decimals. So we could end up with 2232.2323.2323 or even 2313.......123123....21. I think this might be close enough for me to work with though, so I appreciate your time with this!

Answer (score 1):

This is like using a cannon to kill a fly, but it will work.

```
      myForm = this.fb.group({
         question_number: null,
      });
      this.myForm.controls['question_number'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
         this.myForm.controls['question_number'].setValue(value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g), ''))
      });
```

Is not a good practise to subscribe to an input, but this will work until you find something better (:

Comment: when setting value inside a valueChanges subscription use { emitEvent: false } otherwise you will end up with an infinite loop